# How do you relativize a replacement axiom in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm reading the section 'Natural Models' in Enderton's 'Elements of Set Theory' p 249. Theorem 9L states that if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal then all the axioms of ZFC are true in $V_\kappa$. Enderton explains that to say a formula $\sigma$ is true in set $M$ is to say that $\sigma^M$ is true, where $\sigma^M$ denotes the formula obtained from $\sigma$ by replacing terms like $\forall x$ with $\forall x\in M$ and $\exists x$ with $\exists x\in M$. $\sigma^M$ is called the **relativization** of $\sigma$ to $M$.

Intuitively, a replacement axiom in $V_\kappa$ ought to take some function $F:V_\kappa\to V_\kappa$ and assert that the image of any set $A\in V_\kappa$ under $F$ is in $V_\kappa$. But I don't think this is what we get if we follow Enderton's recipe. Let's take a specific replacement axiom in ZFC and see how it relativizes to $V_\kappa$. First, we need a function. Or rather, we need a formula $\phi(x,y)$ with the property that $$\forall x:\forall y_1:\forall y_2: \phi(x,y_1)\wedge \phi(x,y_2)\implies y_1 = y_2$$

I will let $\phi(x,y)$ denote $x = y\vee \forall z:z\in V_\kappa$. Since not every set is in $V_\kappa$ this is equivalent to just stating $x=y$ and clearly has the above property. The corresponding replacement axiom $\sigma$ is $$\forall A: \exists B: \forall y: y\in B\iff \exists x\in A: \phi(x,y)$$

But $\sigma$ isn't true in $V_\kappa$. $\phi^{V_\kappa}(x,y)$ states $x = y\vee \forall z\in V_\kappa:z\in V_\kappa$ which is always true. So $\sigma^{V_\kappa}$ effectively states

$$\forall A\in V_\kappa: \exists B\in V_\kappa: \forall y\in V_\kappa: y\in B\iff \exists x\in A : \texttt{true}$$

So as long as $A\neq \emptyset$ we have $B = V_\kappa$ which is not a member of $V_\kappa$. Hence, not all of the replacement axioms are true in $V_\kappa$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I forgot about the original way that Enderton formulates the replacement axioms. It's a bit cumbersome but it solves the problem. Take *any* formula $\phi(x,y)$ not using the symbol '$B$'. Then we have the replacement axiom $$(\forall x: \forall y_1: \forall y_2: \phi(x,y_1)\wedge \phi(x,y_2) \implies y_1 = y_2) \implies (\forall A: \exists B: \forall y: y\in B \iff \exists x\in A: \phi(x,y))$$ This way the "function" aspect of the axiom is preserved when you relativize.